# Trying to insert into sqlite database from SQLiteOpenHelper causes GC_CONCURRENT freed

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert, oncreate

I've been working my way through my first android database implementation over the last few days.

Today, I've been trying to implement SQLiteOpenHelper. From the onCreate(); method I can successfully create the new database (yay).

The issue I'm running into is this: This is for an app that is already operational for iOS. The iOS database is at version 5. If I set this Android database to 5 initially, none of the migration methods get run from onUpgrade();. So I tried running these methods methods from the onCreate() method. The migration methods essentially setup some default values and add some indexes to the database.

But, any time I try to run an insert command I get an endless stream of GC_CONCURRENT freed ... readout in logcat, and my UI never advances passed some barebones structure (i.e., background and action bar).

Here is what I'm doing:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {   
    Log.d(LOG, "creating database and tables.");
    // * Execute create tables
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LANDMARKS);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FAVORITES);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FRIENDS);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_WISHLIST);

    migrateDatabaseToVersion_1(db);

    Log.d(LOG, "finished creating database and tables");
}

private void migrateDatabaseToVersion_1(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    ContentValues landmarkValues = new ContentValues();
    landmarkValues.put(COLUMN_PCI, "initial");
    landmarkValues.put(COLUMN_PRI, 1);
    landmarkValues.put(COLUMN_LANDMARK_NAME, "w_monument");
    landmarkValues.put(COLUMN_LANDMARK_COORDINATE_X, "38.8895 N");
    landmarkValues.put(COLUMN_LANDMARK_COORDINATE_Y, "77.0352 W");
    landmarkValues.put(COLUMN_LANDMARK_NUMBER_OF_VISITS, 0);
    landmarkValues.put(COLUMN_LANDMARK_FAVORITE, 0);
    landmarkValues.put(COLUMN_LANDMARK_EST, "1970-01-01");
    landmarkValues.put(COLUMN_LANDMARK_TAG, "washington");
    landmarkValues.put(COLUMN_LANDMARK_NOTES, "type notes here");
    landmarkValues.putNull(COLUMN_LANDMARK_PHOTO);
    landmarkValues.put(COLUMN_LANDMARK_COMMON_NAME, "Washington Monument");
    landmarkValues.put(COLUMN_LANDMARK_DELETED, 0);


    long landmarkId = db.insert(TABLE_LANDMARKS, null, landmarkValues);
    if (landmarkId != 0) {
        Log.d(LOG, "default landmark data inserted");
    }
}
```

I've been working at this all day and just cant seem to figure things out. I tried not using the ContentValues class, and just running the db.execSQL but I received the same result: a stream of never ending CG_CONCURRENT freed ... in Logcat and my UI not loading... No crash, just nothing - and the onCreate() method never finishes.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: OK - I stopped trying to read the database at the same time as I was adding the default values, and the insert worked... What is the best way to go about this? App launches, first view is trying to access database stored data but the info is being inserted??

Comment: Switched to using Loader and LoaderManger and everything is working as it should now - thanks to any that glanced at this.

Answer (score 0):

I was just simply doing things wrong - mistakes of a newb. Switched to using Loaders and LoaderManager and now everything is working as it should.

The issue was likely related to trying to read and write to the db at the same time.